# Add user method not working: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Getting the following error when I'm trying to execute the code below.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'.
```

Don't mind the security behind the add user part since this is a testing project for learning purposes only.

```
public void AddUser(User user) {
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=Community;User Id=XXX;Password=XXX;");
    string sql = "INSERT INTO User (Username, Password) VALUES(@Username, @Password)";
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", user.Username);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", user.Password);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO [User]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User is a Keyword in SQL. Put it into Brackets `[User]`

Comment: Oh yeah, totally forgot about that part, thanks!

Comment: if you would have entered it in your Management Studio you would have noticed the keyword highlighting immediately :)

Answer (score 0):

So, even though you have a table called `User`, it is also a reserved keyword in SQL Server. To escape that, use `[User]`:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO User (Username, Password) VALUES(@Username, @Password)";
```